# JHipster+consul rate-limit with prod profile throwing ClassNotFound exception

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, hazelcast, consul

I am using typical JHipster[4.14.0] microservices stack (JHipster Gateway + UAA + 2 microservices + consul[0.9.3]). Postgres as database and Hazelcast is enabled in project. Using 'dev' profile, rate limit is working fine in JHipster, I've tested it, no exceptions. Now I'm testing it with 'prod' profile. I've made following changes on application-prod.yml

```
gateway:
    rate-limiting:
        enabled: true
        limit: 3
        duration-in-seconds: 30
    authorized-microservices-endpoints: # Access Control Policy, if left empty for a route, all endpoints will be accessible
        app1: /api # recommended prod configuration
```

But while running, I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException and the calls are failing. Am i missing something in order to use the rate-limit in prod profile? Please note that bucket4j-core & bucket4j-jcache are present in main pom.xml of gateway.

```
    com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.preRoute(FilterProcessor.java:133)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.preRoute(ZuulRunner.java:105)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.preRoute(ZuulServlet.java:125)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.web.filter.RefreshTokenFilter.doFilter(RefreshTokenFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.cache.processor.EntryProcessorException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.ExecuteProcessor
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.CacheProxy.invoke(CacheProxy.java:250)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.JCacheProxy.execute(JCacheProxy.java:51)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.GridBucket.execute(GridBucket.java:162)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.GridBucket.tryConsumeImpl(GridBucket.java:77)
    at io.github.bucket4j.AbstractBucket.tryConsume(AbstractBucket.java:159)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.gateway.ratelimiting.RateLimitingFilter.run(RateLimitingFilter.java:80)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.ExecuteProcessor
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:267)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:570)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.operation.CacheEntryProcessorOperation.readInternal(CacheEntryProcessorOperation.java:131)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.readData(Operation.java:606)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:185)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:339)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:394)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.join(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.CacheProxy.invoke(CacheProxy.java:242)
    ... 123 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.ExecuteProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:173)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:591)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:267)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:570)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.operation.CacheEntryProcessorOperation.readInternal(CacheEntryProcessorOperation.java:131)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.readData(Operation.java:606)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:185)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:339)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:394)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
```

Comment: Have you unzipped the prod war file to confirm the class is really missing?

Comment: I'm running it right within Intellij using 'prod' spring-boot profile, and can see this exception in Gateway process.

Comment: Well then try running it using maven or gradle to see if the issue is related to the way you run it in IntelliJ.

Comment: I've same issue with docker-compose [outside intellij] with prod profile [jhipster docker-compose]. Note that I've build all the 4 projects with -Pprod. If i disable the rate-limit, it's fine, hence it has to be related with rate-limit.

Comment: Yes it is related as bucket4j is only used for rate limiting. Still you haven't answered my questions/suggestions.

Comment: I've run all these projects on command line with maven, and have seen this exception which fails all the calls. Tried several times. However if i stop the gateway while the microservices are running and starts again, then few of the times, i got it working, not always. Have tried several times. It seems there is a race condition [could it be similar to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8972???]. By the way, on command line, i even start getting the above mentioned exception on UAA but that could be because i enabled swagger on UAA prod profile just for test purpose.

Comment: I think you should open an issue on jhipster github project with all required details